# What can I correct to run my Node app in PuTTY?

Tags: putty

I'm trying to deploy my Node JS app for the first time in DigitalOcean and am following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RE2PLyFqCzE&t=1515s

I've created a repository in Github and am at the stage where I've also installed Node on the server but am unable to star the app with the command: 'npm start'. Please advise. 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuzdA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the script object in package.json

For Example:
"scripts": { 
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --ignore public/",
    "dev": "webpack -wd"
  },

Comment: Maybe not? Please see this screenshot: [imgur](http://imgur.com/a/Aq6OK) Sorry I'm just learning

Comment: this will help you